# Llenar combo box usando Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

Estoy comenzando con spring mvc y quisiera saber la manera de llenar un `select`, he visto ejemplos en Internet pero no son muy claros, no se si existe una manera sencilla y clara, se que se utiliza el `form:options` pero quisiera un ejemplo completo y detallado con sus controladores, archivos jsp completos, encontre este codigo de ejemplo

```
@RequestMapping(value="/phone-page")
private ModelAndView selectTag() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("phone-form");

    Map< String, String > phones = new HashMap<String, String>();
    phones.put("samsung", "SAMSUNG");
    phones.put("nokia", "NOKIA");
    phones.put("iphone", "IPHONE");

    mav.addObject("phonesMap", phones);
    mav.addObject("smartphone", new Smartphone());

    return mav;
}
```

Codigo html

```html
<h1>Phone page</h1>
Select phone:
<form:form method="POST" commandName="smartphone" action="phone-result.html">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <form:select path="phone" items="${phonesMap}"/>
        </ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

Mis dudas son ¿por que es necesaria esta linea?

```
mav.addObject("smartphone", new Smartphone());
```

¿Porque el form tiene que llevar esto?

```
commandName="smartphone"
```

Gracias.

Comment: puede poner los ejemplos que ha visto, y señalar las partes que no tiene muy claras, quizas eso ayude a algun usuario a saber que es lo que no entiende. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

> Mis dudas son ¿por que es necesaria esta linea?
>
> > mav.addObject("smartphone", new Smartphone());

En esta línea se crea una instancia de Smartphone y se pasa a la vista. Sus valores son los que se cargarán en la jsp. Es decir, si en objeto Smartphone   la propiedad "phone" tiene un valor determinado, ese valor es el que se mostraría seleccionado en el select de la jsp.

> ¿Porque el form tiene que llevar esto?
>
> > commandName="smartphone"

El valor del atributo "commandName" indica el nombre de la variable que se usa para linkar los datos del formulario con una variable del controlador. En este caso una variable llamada "smartphone" y se corresponde con variable "smartphone" que tienes en el controlador:

```
mav.addObject("smartphone", new Smartphone());
```

En las nuevas versiones de Spring se recomienda el uso de la etiqueta modelAttribute en lugar de commandName. Su funcionamiento es el mismo:

```
modelAttribute="smartphone"
```

Comment: Hola @Lemi si ésta o alguna respuesta ha solucionado tu pregunta por favor considera aceptarla como respuesta correcta haciendo clic en la marca verde de aceptación. Esto indica a la 
comunidad que has encontrado la solución y da repuetación ambos, la persona que ha respondido y a ti mismo. No es obligatorio hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

```
mav.addObject("smartphone", new Smartphone());
```

Esta línea dice que enviarás un objeto Smartphone nuevo(con sus valores por defecto) al `mav`, en este caso el mav ha sido creado para enviar todos los valores que desees a la vista `phone-form`, en tu ejemplo no dice como es que se llama el jsp, pero asumo es es `phone-form.jsp`

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("phone-form");
```

El `.jsp` recibe este valor llamado `"smartphone"` y se encuentra con que tiene un formulario llamado de la misma manera

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="smartphone" action="phone-result.html">
```

Lo que Hará el `.jsp` es reemplazar los `paths` del formulario por las propiedades del objeto Smartphone(que en este caso es un `new Smartphone()`)

Por otro lado en el formulario existe un select cuyos  elementos se llenaran con los valores de la variable `${phonesMap}`

```
<form:select path="phone" items="${phonesMap}"/>
```

Esta variable `${phonesMap}`, es un  `HashMap` que contiene 3 elementos enviados desde el controlador siendo `"samsung"` el id y `"SAMSUNG"` el value para el primer elemento del select.

```
Map< String, String > phones = new HashMap<String, String>();
    phones.put("samsung", "SAMSUNG");
    phones.put("nokia", "NOKIA");
    phones.put("iphone", "IPHONE");
mav.addObject("phonesMap", phones);
```

Y para terminar deberias saber que al hacer un submit el formulario irá a donde indica el `action` del formulario

```
@RequestMapping(value="/phone-result.html")
```

En el que puedes recoger el objeto `Smartphone` con el valor del select escogido dentro de su propiedad `phone`